# What would the wavelength be in this Doppler effect example?

Tags: frequency, wavelength, doppler-effect

I'm trying to understand an example of the Doppler effect. Let's say we have an object moving at $100 \ \dfrac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}$ ($27.7 \ \dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$) and emitting a frequency of $200 \ \text{Hz}$. Now assume the speed of sound is $340 \ \dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$. Since we know that frequency is equal to the speed of sound over the wavelength, wouldn't the wavelength be $\dfrac{340 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}{200 \ \text{Hz}} = \dfrac{340 \ \text{m}}{200} = 1.7 \ \text{m}$? I saw it said that the wavelength would be $3.4 \ \text{m}$, but that doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: Which wavelength is said to be 3.4 m? The original or the Doppler shifted one?

Comment: @nasu It actually wasn't specified, which is confusing. Is it possible to tell from the context (for those of you that are more experienced)?

Comment: Well, what is the context? I mean, the actual text of the problem and of the solution?

Comment: @nasu It's not a problem, it's literally just a stated hypothetical example, in the same way that I have written.

Comment: So, then who is the one to say that the wavelength is 3.4 m? Ok, it's not a problem but an example. Where does it come from? Where did you see this and what is the actual text? Or you just made it up?

Comment: @nasu It was given to me in some photonics research primer notes. It's just a quick, brief example to illustrate calculations for the Doppler effect. If the example doesn't make sense, then I'll just notify my professor, but I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something obvious on my end.

Comment: As it is in the OP it does not make sense. But it is hard to say without the original text. Maybe you are missing some detail. It does not matter how it was given to you, more relevant would be to see the actual text.

Comment: @nasu I'll have to discuss it with the professor then. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all, because you completely ignored the Doppler Effect. Since here observer is stationary, sound velocity, being a property of the medium would remain $340 \ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$. However, by the time the wave covers the distance of $1$ wavelength, the source has also moved, causing the $\mathbf {effective}$ wavelength to become shorter than what would have been had the source been stationary. Mathematically:
$$\lambda^\prime = \lambda - vT$$ where $v$ is source velocity and $T$ is time period. This means that:
$$f_{\text{app}} = \frac{c}{c-v} f$$ Here $c$ is sound velocity, and $f$ is original frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So where did the $3.4 \ \text{m}$ come from then?

Comment: For this example, it seems to me that we would get $$\dfrac{340}{340 - 27.7} \times 200 = 217.7,$$ so I don't understand where the $3.4 \ \text{m}$ comes from.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is increasing then it means that the source is moving away from the observer. Please read my answer carefully, once.

Comment: I did read your answer, but this doesn't explain where $3.4 \ \text{m}$ came from.

Comment: The wavelength changes because the source moves

Comment: Ok, but what is the calculation that leads to $3.4 \ \text{m}$? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Calculate $f_{app}$ from formula given and use $c=f_{app}\lambda_{app}$.

Comment: What is $\lambda_{\text{app}}$? Is this the same as $\lambda^\prime$? We're not given $T$, so I'm not sure how one is supposed to calculate $\lambda^\prime$.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as $\lambda'$.

Comment: We are not given any $T$, so I don't think this is where $3.4 \ \text{m}$ came from.

Comment: You do know $T$, $T=\frac 1f$. But the answer given in your book can't be correct.

Comment: I get $$217.7 \left(1.7 - 27.7 \times \dfrac{1}{200} \right) = 340,$$ which seems to be the $340 \ \dfrac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$, right? But it still isn't clear where the $3.4 \ \text{m}$ wavelength figure comes from.

Comment: Yes $3.4 m$ is wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.